# What's the fastest way to unroll a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, matrix

How do I turn a matrix:

```
[ 0.12 0.23 0.34 ;
  0.45 0.56 0.67 ;
  0.78 0.89 0.90 ]
```

into a 'coordinate' matrix with a bunch of rows?

```
[ 1 1 0.12 ;
  1 2 0.23 ;
  1 3 0.34 ;
  2 1 0.45 ;
  2 2 0.56 ;
  2 3 0.67 ;
  3 1 0.78 ;
  3 2 0.89 ;
  3 3 0.90 ]
```

(permutation of the rows is irrelevant, it only matters that the data is in this structure)

Right now I'm using a for loop but that takes a long time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an option using `ind2sub`:

```
mat= [ 0.12 0.23 0.34 ;
  0.45 0.56 0.67 ;
  0.78 0.89 0.90 ] ;

[I,J] = ind2sub(size(mat), 1:numel(mat));
r=[I', J', mat(:)]

r =

    1.0000    1.0000    0.1200
    2.0000    1.0000    0.4500
    3.0000    1.0000    0.7800
    1.0000    2.0000    0.2300
    2.0000    2.0000    0.5600
    3.0000    2.0000    0.8900
    1.0000    3.0000    0.3400
    2.0000    3.0000    0.6700
    3.0000    3.0000    0.9000
```

**Note** that the indices are reversed compared to your example.

Comment: Alternatively, dropping one set of intermediates for neatness, `ind2sub(size(A), 1:numel(A))`

Comment: He said a permutation of the rows is irrelevant, so this should be just as fine. The rows as such are still the same. (Referring to your note btw)

Answer (score 6):

```
A = [ .12 .23 .34 ;
      .45 .56 .67 ;
      .78 .89 .90 ];

[ii jj] = meshgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2));
B = A.';
R = [ii(:) jj(:) B(:)];
```

If you don't mind a different order (according to your edit), you can do it more easily:

```
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2));
R = [ii(:) jj(:) A(:)];
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to generating the row/col indexes with `meshgrid`, you can use all three outputs of `find` as follows:

```
[II,JJ,AA]= find(A.'); %' note the transpose since you want to read across
M = [JJ II AA]
M =
            1            1         0.12
            1            2         0.23
            1            3         0.34
            2            1         0.45
            2            2         0.56
            2            3         0.67
            3            1         0.78
            3            2         0.89
            3            3          0.9
```

Limited application because *zeros get lost*.  Nasty, but correct workaround (thanks user664303):

```
B = A.'; v = B == 0; %' transpose to read across, otherwise work directly with A
[II, JJ, AA] = find(B + v);
M = [JJ II AA-v(:)];
```

Needless to say, I would recommend one of the other solutions.  :)  In particular, `ndgrid` is the most natural solution to obtaining the row,col inds.

Comment: Oh, but zeros... hmmm

Comment: A not very elegant solution to cover the case with zeros: add and then subtract `min(A(:))+1`

Comment: Bug fix and no loss of accuracy: `B = A.'; v = B == 0; [II, JJ, AA] = find(B + v); M = [JJ II AA-v(:)];`

Comment: @user664303: Thanks for the suggestion.  Not even I would use this `find` method, but hey... it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I find `ndgrid` to be the most natural solution, but here's a fun way to do it manually with the odd couple of `kron` and `repmat`:

```
M = [kron(1:size(A,2),ones(1,size(A,1))).' ...  %' row indexes
     repmat((1:size(A,1))',size(A,2),1) ...     %' col indexes
     reshape(A.',[],1)]                         %' matrix values, read across
```

Simple adjustment to read down, as is natural in MATLAB:

```
M = [repmat((1:size(A,1))',size(A,2),1) ...     %' row indexes (still)
     kron(1:size(A,2),ones(1,size(A,1))).' ...  %' column indexes
     A(:)]                                      %  matrix values, read down
```

(Also since my first answer was obscenely hackish.)

---

I also find [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) to be a nice tool to replicate each element at a time rather than than the entire array at a time, as `repmat` does.  For example:

```
>> 1:size(A,2)
ans =
     1     2     3
>> kron(1:size(A,2),ones(1,size(A,1)))
ans =
     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
```

Taking this a bit further, we can generate a new function called `repel` to replicate elements of an array as opposed to the whole array:

```
>> repel = @(x,m,n) kron(x,ones(m,n));
>> repel(1:4,1,2)
ans =
     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4
>> repel(1:3,2,2)
ans =
     1     1     2     2     3     3
     1     1     2     2     3     3
```