# finding & saving RGB value of some selected pixels of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, pixel

I selected some pixels from an RGB image using `ginput`. Now I need a code to extract RGB value of all of selected pixels in a same time and save them in coordinate matrix of pixels. Any suggestion?

```
A=imread('AMAR.jpg');
imshow(A)
samp1= ginput(A)
```

`samp1` is <47x5 double>

some results are:

95  92
95  81
99  66
97  66
100 58
105 51
108 42
116 33

Comment: Can you give a bit of code that shows how you extract single values? Typically if you have `rgbMatrix(N, N, 3)` you can extract a region `region = rgbMatrix(5:10, 6:12, :);` to get a rectangular region. Adapt for your needs...

Comment: ` A=imread('AMAR.jpg');
imshow(A)
samp1= ginput(A)`

and these are coordinates of some pixels:
samp1 =

    95    92
    95    81
    99    66
    97    66
   100    58
   105    51
   108    42
   116    33
   124    25
   133    18
   141    14
   151    10
   164     9
   173     9
   186    10
   200    14

Comment: The input argument to `ginput(N)` is the number of points to acquire from the currently displayed image. Are you wanting RGB values for arbitrary clicked points (as in my answer), or rectangular regions?

Comment: @chappjc yes. clicked points

Answer (score 1):

Say you click on `N` points in an RGB image:

```
N=4;
imagesc(img)
[x,y]=ginput(N);
```

The `x`,`y` values can be used to lookup the RGB vector for each location:

```
x = round(x(:)); y = round(y(:));
locs = sub2ind(size(img),repmat(y,3,1),repmat(x,3,1),kron(1:3,ones(1,N)).'); %'
RGBvals = reshape(img(locs),N,3)
```

That gives you an `N`-by-3 array of RGB values for each point.  Use the interactive tool `impixelregion` to visually verify the color values.

Note: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21708855/2778484) for a bit about `kron` that should hopefully deflate any mystery about its use here.

Answer (score 1):

@chappjc's answer would work; I would like to offer a small change that is a bit more "readable":

First - call `ginput` without any arguments. It will keep accumulating points clicked until you hit "enter". A little more user friendly.

Second - there's a time and a place for vectorization. When you have just a handful of points (namely, one point per click) it is unlikely that the speedup of vectorized code is worth the pain of `sub2ind, repmat, kron...)`.  That leaves us with the following:

```
imshow(A);
disp( 'Click points in the image; press return when finished' );
[xf, yf] = ginput;

xi = round(xf);
yi = round(yf);

N = numel(xi);
rgbValues = zeros(N, 3);

for ii = 1:numel(xi)
  rgbValues(ii,:) = reshape(A(yi(ii), xi(ii), :), 1, 3);
end
```

This will put the values you want into `rgbValues`.

**Do check** that the values of `xi` and `yi` are returned in the order shown; I *think* this is right, but if I'm wrong you would have to use the order `A(xi(ii), yi(ii), :)` when you read the image).

Comment: Good points, plus one. But once you get used to the kinds of tricks in my answer, they come with minimal pain. Conversely, these three letters make my fingers ache: `f`-`o`-`r`.  :)

Comment: @chappjc - there is a time and a place for everything. I actually just ran a benchmark, comparing the two codes. Quite apart from the fact that either of them is blazingly fast compared to the time taken by the user inputting data, when I sum over 10,000 runs my form of code is 3x faster for 10 clicked points - breakeven happens around 100 points clicked. At 500 points "clicked", your code is 3.5x faster. This shows that eliminating `for` loops is not _always_ worth it...

Comment: I quite agree.  I was merely being facetious, and a little self deprecating over my unfounded aversion to loops.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a little self-deprecation. It beats waiting for others to do it.